# Estoy desarrollando un login y registro de usuarios en flask,html y PostgreSQL, pero hay un error que no logro solucionar. Error: 405

Tags: html, postgresql, flask

``login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="name" required>
            <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <a href="register.html" class="link">No tienes una cuenta? Registrate!</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

``register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="name" required>
            <br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
            <a href="login.html" class="link">ya tienes una cuenta? Ingresa aqui!</a>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

``app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24) 
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0


 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:username:password@server/db' 
***(Escrito asi por seguridad. El codigo original contiene los datos correctos de la base de datos.)***
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

        new_user = User(name=name, email=email, password=password)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            return "Email ya registrado. Por favor pruebe con otro."

    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

       user = User.query.filter_by(email=email, password=password).first()

        if user:
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            return "Bienvenido, " + user.name
        else:
            return "Email o contraseña incorrectos"

    return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

En este ejemplo que contiene el archivo completo del proyecto, hay un problema, y es que al ejecutar el proyecto me sale el siguiente mensaje: "Error loading resource: Server responded with a status of 405 ().....chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1
Lei que se puede deber a errores en la ruta o las variables, pero honestamente no encontre el error. Pueden ayudarme?
Tambien quiero destacar que al probarlo en la consola, no me marca ninguna linea que puede estar fallando.